# Position for element with css

Tags: html, css

As we usually see, the structure of hgroup maybe like this

```
h1
h2
h3
...
```

But in my case, the h3 come first the h2, we have something like this:

```
h3
h2
```

But again I must follow design, I must style for h2 come first:

```
h2
h3
```

For easy to image, please view here:
http://cdpn.io/dfnjo

I choose to use position, it worked but I don't satisfy because I can't control how many texts the editor will put in, so if the h2 has a lot text, it may overlap the text of h3.(Please try to add more text for h2).

Please advise me do without Javascript, just CSS only!

Thanks

Comment: There are not some methods to count char or get element width only using css

Comment: I really don't think what you're asking is possible with CSS.  You want to move the CSS elements by an unknown amount on the page? You will either need JS for this or you need to redesign your logic.

Comment: I would like to change the structure if I can and don't need to use position for these element, but the structure is fixed by others, and I don't have any permission to use Javascript here. So if I know the amount of text as the h2 has max two lines of text, the h3 has max three lines of text, do we have any method here?

Comment: **Using `h3` before `h2` is really bad for SEO!**

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this situation with CSS, because CSS has not if-else statements.

But there is a way to apply if-else statements with SASS(SCSS). Research about it , it provides to use functions, variables for while statments etc.. But it can't change html elements nested lists.

Comment: I just use pure css, no SASS or LESS, but thank for your help, I will leave this question here.

Answer (score -1):

```
$("h2").insertBefore($("h2").prev());
```

or if they don't come in order,

```
$("h2").insertBefore($("h3"));
```

Comment: he clearly edited it after my answer, because I read it a few times, I couldn't understand the question. Anyway, I apologize. I can't think of anything to change the structure of html without javascript. Css will work only with position, which like you said you can't control the content and height.

Comment: I can't comment on the original post, but even if you knew the size of text, that would translate to height of h3/h2. in this case, you still can't use this information, because it is done by javascript.